# Background to be executed only once in cucumber

Tags: cucumber-jvm

I have the cucumber feature as below. I would like the background to be executed only once not for each line in the examples. How do i do that.

Feature: Bulk import of portfolios through the UI

```
Background: Bulk import of portfolios and treaties
    Given the user logs into “dev” environment as “User ” with password "Password1"
    And the user Chooses to import a portfolio providing SQLServer as "10.10.10.10”
    And the user chooses uploaded Anytime
    And the user enters the filter criteria for “Client_EDM”
    And the user expands the Edm
    And the user expands the portfolios dropdown
    And the user chooses the Name as "UK COM for v0.7"
    And the user chooses the contract as ""

  Scenario Outline: Import of portfolio
    Given the user clicks on Import button
    And the user specifies the ImportJobName as "<ImportName>"
    And the user specifies the project "<EDM>"
    And the user specifies the structure "<StructureName>"
    And the user submits a portfolio for Import
    Examples:
      | EDM              | ImportName           | StructureName|
      |Client1_EDM|EUFL_UK_Com_Import100|EUFLCom_Import101|
      |Client2_EDM|EUFL_UK_Com_Import101|EUFLCom_Import101|
```

Tagging the Scenario Outline as @attribute or adding @before for each of the background step will not solve my problem.. Any suggestions on how to go about doing it.?

Comment: whole idea of Background is to be executed every time for every scenario. Maybe it makes sense to separate those steps into another file and execute it first? Or maybe you want to use @after annotation and clean up after your test was executed?

Answer (score 0):

```
  Scenario: Bulk import of portfolios and treaties
    Given the user logs into “dev” environment as “User ” with password "Password1"
    And the user Chooses to import a portfolio providing SQLServer as "10.10.10.10”
    And the user chooses uploaded Anytime
    And the user enters the filter criteria for “Client_EDM”
    And the user expands the Edm
    And the user expands the portfolios dropdown
    And the user chooses the Name as "UK COM for v0.7"
    And the user chooses the contract as ""

  Scenario Outline: Import of portfolio
    Given the user clicks on Import button
    And the user specifies the ImportJobName as "<ImportName>"
    And the user specifies the project "<EDM>"
    And the user specifies the structure "<StructureName>"
    And the user submits a portfolio for Import
    Examples:
      | EDM              | ImportName           | StructureName|
      |Client1_EDM|EUFL_UK_Com_Import100|EUFLCom_Import101|
      |Client2_EDM|EUFL_UK_Com_Import101|EUFLCom_Import101|
```

Comment: Not really how it's intended, but interesting solution!